# Python Flask not saving to folder

Tags: python, flask

i am trying to create a Python/Flask app where the user saves an image to a local folder . It creates the folder , i get the "has been uploaded" success page but the image was not saved in the folder

this is my .py code

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")

@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images/')
    print(target)

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
        print(file)
        filename = file.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)

    return render_template("complete.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

this is my .html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload here</h1>
<form id="upload-form" action="{{url_for('upload')}}" methods="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="send">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your html markup where you define the form. It should say:

```
<form id="upload-form" action="{{url_for('upload')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

As in `method="POST"` instead of `methods="POST"`

Comment: Wow that was a bit embarassing.Thank you very much for taking the time and helping me out with this

Comment: No worries. Happens to the best of us!

Comment: How would i go now if i wanted to save the image in the folder under a different name of my own choosing ? What would i have to do in the form ?

Comment: You can either rename the destination file aster you `file.save()` it, or you can even give it an alternative destination: `destination = "/".join([target, 'newfilename.extension'])`